# How to convert an array of objects into a single string - WHERE NOT EVERY ELEMENT IS A STRING - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to make this array into one string - quotation marks around the whole thing - not affecting the individual elements - therefore JSON.stringify doesnt work.

```
[ { name: 'red', id: '1' },
  { name: 'yellow', id: '2' },
  { name: 'black', id: '3' },
  { name: 'white', id: '4' } ]
```

needs to be

```
"[ { name: 'red', id: '1' },
 { name: 'yellow', id: '2' },
 { name: 'black', id: '3' },
 { name: 'white', id: '4' } ]"
```

I do not want to make every element of the array a string, I just want to put quotation marks around the whole thing. I've tried doing arr.join() and i just get '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'
Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: json.stringify(data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify`

```js
var x=[ { name: 'red', id: '1' },
  { name: 'yellow', id: '2' },
  { name: 'black', id: '3' },
  { name: 'white', id: '4' } ];
  
  var y=JSON.stringify(x);
  alert(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
  { name: 'red', id: '1' },
  { name: 'yellow', id: '2' },
  { name: 'black', id: '3' },
  { name: 'white', id: '4' }
];
  
let string = JSON.stringify( arr );

console.log( typeof string );
```

[image]

Comment: this puts every element in quotation marks, and not the whole thing... which is the opposite of what i want to do

Comment: No. It works absolutely right. See attached picture. The checking of type in code snippet proves it.